# unix sed remove adapter names

Tags: text-processing, sed

I would like to pipe the output to `sed` and remove the below adapter names using `sed` and group the values with commas

```
ent13: 16 3979 ent12: 211 411 3978 ent11: 15 3977 ent10: 111 178 179 311 511 1719 3976
```

Comment: You might want to re-edit with code tags (see the `?` on the top right of the editor). Pay attention to the preview, so we know exactly what your input is. Also, what are "adapter names"?

Comment: It's been edited by @Inian, but I'm unsure if your input is meant to be all on one line.

Comment: @Sparhawk: OP meant it to be on the same line I suppose

Comment: @Sparhawk adapter names are starting with entXX:  (eg:ent13) the output is on the same line.

Comment: ... so the result is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could a `sed` to first remove the pattern containing `ent` and then put the spacing away and replace it with `,` as

```
sed 's/ent[0-9][0-9]: //g; s/ /,/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace spaces by commas, remove words before colons, remove the leading space, remove commas before spaces:

```
sed 's/ /,/g; s/[^,]*:,/ /g;s/^ //;s/, / /g'
```

Output:

```
16,3979 211,411,3978 15,3977 111,178,179,311,511,1719,3976
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk` or `mawk` (to support regular expressions in `RS`):

```
$ mawk -v RS='ent[0-9][0-9]: ' -v ORS=' ' -v FS=' ' -v OFS=',' '
    $1 != "" { $1=$1; print }
    END      { printf("\n") }' <file
16,3979 211,411,3978 15,3977 111,178,179,311,511,1719,3976
```

Or, equivalently,

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN    { RS="ent[0-9][0-9]: "; ORS=FS=" "; OFS="," }
        $1 != "" { $1=$1; print } 
        END      { printf("\n") }' <file
16,3979 211,411,3978 15,3977 111,178,179,311,511,1719,3976
```

This treats the single line as a set of records separated by `entNN:` (where `N` is some digit).  Each record is read as a set of space-delimited fields.

The `$1 != ""` test skips the first empty record (there's nothing before the first record separator) and the corresponding block reformats the record for output by simply doing `$1=$1`.  This will cause `awk` to reformat it using the supplied `ORS` and `OFS` values.

Answer (score 0):

Does "group the values with commas" mean "separate each adapter's numbers with a comma from other adapters'"? Then, try

```
sed 's/ *ent[0-9][0-9]: /, /g; s/^, //g' file
16 3979, 211 411 3978, 15 3977, 111 178 179 311 511 1719 3976
```